# Is there a better way to achieve the same result with {f[#],g[#]}&@list?

Tags: functions, coding-style

I have found myself recently typing over and over again similar code, namely something that looks like `{f[#],g[#]}&@list`. Is there a '*better*' way to achieve the same result?

I have come up with just this alternative `Through[{f,g}[list]]`.

Can you think of a better way to do something like `{First[#],Rest[#]}&@list` or `{Mean[#],StandardDeviation[#]}&@list`?

Also, is the way that `Through` is used, appropriate?

---

**update:**
I would like to refrain from using `Map`, or `Apply` if that is possible. I just want a '*native*' robust way to manipulate lists or parts of lists in '*one pass*' so to speak.

**update2:**  I am searching for a better, robust way to apply a series of functions on a list, quickly, reliably and with as little as possible typing involved. I don't have a problem to settle for an answer in the negative, or explore more specialized solutions, see comment on `TakeDrop[]`.

Comment: Personally, when I'm in a slot-free mood, I use `Through[]` a lot.

Comment: Single slot alternative: `#@list & /@ {f, g}`

Comment: With a bit more short hand: `Through@{f, g}@list`.  That is what I mostly use.

Comment: @Kuba: I know I didn't include it in the question, but I am trying to keep away from mapping stuff for a while-I'm trying to work over lists with as little as possible use of `Map`.

Comment: It escapes me why `Map` and `Apply` are not native methods for manipulating lists.

Comment: @m_goldberg: I never claimed that `Map` and `Apply` are not *native* methods. What I wrote is that I am looking for ways *other* than using them to achieve the desired result on the use cases I described. Just trying to improve my coding skills by finding new solutions to old problems. I'm sorry if I was not clear about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at functions such as [MinMax](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinMax.html) and [ReIm](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReIm.html) - both introduced very recently in V10.1. It looks like historical need pushed for their creation. You mentioned constructs:

```
{First[#],Rest[#]}&@list
```

and

```
{Mean[#],StandardDeviation[#]}&@list
```

which are robust pairs that probably go always together for you. And you implied repetitive usage. In this case why not do define a function or even better a personal **[package](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpWolframLanguagePackages.html)** of a set of them as, for instance:

```
myMeanDev[list_List] := {Mean[list], StandardDeviation[list]}
```

which reduces your task now, obviously, to just `myMeanDev[list]`. So as a final bright example, your `{First[#],Rest[#]}&@list` case is solved as a builtin function

```
In[1]:= TakeDrop[{a, b, c, d, e}, 1]
Out[1]= {{a}, {b, c, d, e}}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion; setting up a package might be a good idea-I'm still in the process of figuring out what works and what doesn't;I had no idea about the new functionality you hinted at so thanks for that too; I was hopping there would be a better, robust way to apply a series of functions on a list, quickly, reliably and with as little as possible typing involved; `TakeDrop[]` is indeed an instance of what I was looking for, albeit too specialized but is indeed one **better alternative** to what I used, so thanks for that too;